# Excel VBA calendar not showing next year

Tags: excel, vba, calendar

I copied some code for a calendar to select a date and enter it in a form. The calendar is not moving on to 2023. Here is the code, or at least the bit that I think covers it.

You can see the bit where the message ["Calendar doesn't support year after " & iLastYear & "."] appears.

I tried a few changes but they didn't work. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

---

```
Option Explicit
Public InputDate

Private Sub cmbMonth_Change()
    
    Call Change_Heading 'Change Calendar as per Month Selection
    Call HighlightInputDate ' Highlight day if inptut date is available
        
End Sub

Private Sub cmbYear_Change()
    
    Call Change_Heading ' 'Change Calendar as per Year Selection
    Call HighlightInputDate ' Highlight day if inptut date is available
    
End Sub

'Subroutine to Change the Heading of Calendar on Month and Year Change
Private Sub Change_Heading()

    Dim iMonth As Integer
    Dim iYear As Integer
    
    iMonth = Val(Me.cmbMonth.ListIndex) + 1
    iYear = Val(Me.cmbYear.Value)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Me.lblMonthName.Caption = Format(DateSerial(iYear, iMonth, 1), "MMMM YYYY")
    
    Call AssignDay(iMonth, iYear)
    
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub lblLeft_Click()

    Dim iCurrentMonth As Integer
    Dim iFirstYear As Integer
    Dim iCurrentYear As Integer
    
    iFirstYear = Me.cmbYear.List(0)
    iCurrentYear = Me.cmbYear.List(Me.cmbYear.ListIndex)
    iCurrentMonth = Me.cmbMonth.ListIndex + 1
    
    If iCurrentMonth = 1 Then
        If iCurrentYear > iFirstYear Then
            Me.cmbYear.Value = iCurrentYear - 1
            Me.cmbMonth.Value = Me.cmbMonth.List(11)
        Else
            
            MsgBox "Calendar doesn't support year before " & iCurrentYear & "."
            
        End If
    Else
        
        Me.cmbMonth.Value = Me.cmbMonth.List(Me.cmbMonth.ListIndex - 1)
    
    End If
   
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub lblLeft_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    Me.lblLeft.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub lblLeft_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    
    Me.lblLeft.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub lblRight_Click()

    Dim iCurrentMonth As Integer
    Dim iLastYear As Integer
    Dim iCurrentYear As Integer
    'tried editing the next row from minus 1 to plus 1 but it didn't work
    iLastYear = Me.cmbYear.List(Me.cmbYear.ListCount - 1)
    iCurrentYear = Me.cmbYear.List(Me.cmbYear.ListIndex)
    iCurrentMonth = Me.cmbMonth.ListIndex + 1
    
    If iCurrentMonth = 12 Then
    'tried adding an = sign to the next row
        If iCurrentYear < iLastYear Then
            Me.cmbYear.Value = iCurrentYear + 1
            Me.cmbMonth.Value = Me.cmbMonth.List(0)
        Else
        
             MsgBox "Calendar doesn't support year after " & iLastYear & "."
        
        End If
        
    Else
        
        Me.cmbMonth.Value = Me.cmbMonth.List(iCurrentMonth)
    
    End If
    
    
    
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub lblRight_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    Me.lblRight.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub lblRight_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    
    Me.lblRight.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
     
    
    If IsDate(InputDate) Then
        
        Dim iDay As Integer
        Dim iMonth As Integer
        Dim sMonthName As String
        Dim iYear As Integer
        Dim iLastYear As Integer
        
        iDay = Val(Format(InputDate, "dd"))
        iMonth = Val(Format(InputDate, "mm"))
        sMonthName = Format(InputDate, "mmmm")
        iYear = Val(Format(InputDate, "YYYY"))
        iLastYear = Me.cmbYear.List(Me.cmbYear.ListCount - 1)
        
        If iYear > iLastYear Then Exit Sub ' If year of date provided is out of range then do nothing
        
        Me.cmbMonth.Value = sMonthName ' Assigning Month to Month Combobox
        Me.cmbYear.Value = iYear ' Assigning Year to Year Combobox (AND THEN YOU TRIED ADDING 1 TO IT BUT IT DIDN'T WORK)
        
        Call Highlight_SelectedDate(iDay) ' Subroutine to highlight the selected day coming from input parameter
        
        
    End If

    
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With MyCalendar
        Height = 300
        Width = 420
    End With



    Call Add_Month ' Subroutine to add month in Month Dropdown
    
    Call Add_Year ' Subroutine to add year in Year Dropdown
    
    Me.txtDay.Value = ""
    
    Me.cmbMonth.Value = Format(Date, "MMMM")
    
    Me.cmbYear.Value = Format(Date, "YYYY")
    
    Me.lblMonthName.Caption = Format(Date, "MMMM YYYY")
    
    Dim iMonth As Integer
    Dim iYear As Integer
    
    iMonth = Val(Me.cmbMonth.ListIndex) + 1
    iYear = Val(Me.cmbYear.Value)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Call AssignDay(iMonth, iYear)
    
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Add_Month()

    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = 1
    
    Me.cmbMonth.Clear
    
    For i = 1 To 12

        Me.cmbMonth.AddItem Format(DateSerial(1, i, 1), "MMMM")
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Add_Year()


    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iCurrentYear As Integer
    
    iCurrentYear = Val(Format(Date, "YYYY")) - 60
    
    Me.cmbYear.Clear
    
    For i = iCurrentYear To (iCurrentYear + 60)

        Me.cmbYear.AddItem i
        
    Next i
    

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub HighlightInputDate() 'Highlight Day if Input date and available date are matching

    If IsDate(InputDate) Then
        
        Dim iDay As Integer
        Dim sMonthName As String
        Dim iYear As Integer
        
        
        iDay = Val(Format(InputDate, "dd"))
        sMonthName = Format(InputDate, "mmmm")
        iYear = Val(Format(InputDate, "YYYY"))
        
        If iYear = Val(Me.cmbYear.Value) And sMonthName = Me.cmbMonth.Value Then
        
            Call Highlight_SelectedDate(iDay) ' Subroutine to highlight the selected day coming from input parameter
        Else
        
            Me.Tick.Visible = False
        
        End If
        
    End If


End Sub
```

I tried adding 1 to a few variables, I have commented in the code I pasted with what I tried.

Comment: In sub `Add_Year()` change 60 to 61 or however many future years you want `For i = iCurrentYear To (iCurrentYear + 60)`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That's great thank you. Sorry for not trimming my code more, I didn't want to cut anything out that mattered.